# Android studio 3.0.1 shows Error:CreateProcess error=216

Tags: android, android-studio

Am new to Android so i installed android Studio 3.0.1 and JDK on windows 8.1 and it is show this message Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher

Comment: Please i need your help, am using 32bit system and JDK 1.8

Comment: Use internet search. There's already answer to this